# How to set a gpio pin to high and make it visible in /sys/class/gpio?

Tags: kernel, gpio, drivers

I am very new to kernel programming, and I want to set a GPIO pin in active high state when the board boots up. Where can I do this in the kernel?

I could do this after the board boots by `exporting` that pin into
`/sys/class/gpio`, but I want this to be `exported` already with active HIGH state.

The reason I need it to be started by kernel is that I need to power on a LED while it is booting.

The board I'm using is PC Engines Alix3d2 with AMD CS5535 Geode processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did this with the example given [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/kernel-gpio-programming-buttons-and-leds/)